# nginx - shorter proxy_pass configuration

Tags: proxy, nginx

I am setting up the proxy by using nginx. Imaging that the I want to add bunch of server_name to the same configuration:

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
    server_name 1.abc.org;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    location / {
           proxy_pass https://1.abc.org;
           include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

I want to add bunch of server_name:

it should be

```
server {
listen 1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
server_name $server_name;
access_log off;
error_log off;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
keepalive_timeout 60;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://$server_name;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

and
server_name = 1.abc.org, 2.abc.org, 3.abc.org, 4.abc.org, aish.abc.org...

then I can do the easier work by adding the server_name like the line above, don't need to copy over the block of configuration. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using an upstream block

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com weight=5;
  server backend2.example.com:8080;
  server unix:/tmp/backend3;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule